# Pointcuts not intercepting appropriate points

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

**EventServiceAspect.java**

```
public EventServiceAspect{
    @Pointcut(value="call(* com.xyz.ServiceInput.callSetup(..))")
    public void anyCallSetup(){}

    @After("anyCallSetup() && @annotation(publishEventToService)")
    public void publishEvent(JoinPoint jp, PublishEventToService publishEventToService){
       log.warn("batman is here!");
    }
}
```

**SampleClass.java**

```
public SampleClass{
   @PublishEventToService
   public void someFunc(){
       serviceInput.callSetup("testing testing")
   }
}
```

The callSetup is not being intercepted by the Pointcut. Any idea what's wrong with my code?

It's a large configuration file...the relevant part is:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
     default-init-method="init"> 

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class = "true"/>
```

Comment: can you add spring configuration file..

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

http://eggsylife.co.uk/2010/02/03/spring-annotation-based-aop-and-intercepting-the-ball/

and it should be **execution** instead of **call**

Comment: I need to have it as call as I need informtion about SampleClass as well

Comment: If you need `call()` you cannot use Spring AOP because this pointcut type is not supported in this "AOP lite" variant. You need to switch to full AspectJ (see Spring documentation for how to configure LTW, but you can also CTW if you like). There `call()` is supported. P.S.: Your pointcut `call(* com.xyz.ServiceInput.callSetup(..))` still does not match method name `SampleClass.someFunc()`. ;-)